# What to do when online event registration doesn't process?

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, registration, online-registration

We have an event that requires online registration with a fee. It was working well up until today. We have some folks registering, after inputting all their information and hitting submit, the "submit" button goes gray and says "processing" but never processes it.

I've looked through our payment processor, price set, all should be set up correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: any errors you can access such as Drupal error logs or the civicrm ConfigAndLog file? sorry if that sounds technical but not sure of your depth understanding of civi yet ;-)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! To help people to help to answer your question it would be great if you could provide some more detail.  The following information would be helpful: the version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. Drupal, WordPress or Joomla), the payment processor you are using.